# How to blanket implement a non-lifetime trait for a trait with a lifetime parameter in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I want to do a blanket implementation of a foreign trait for an own trait with a lifetime parameter, and will have to make use of that parameter in an AssociatedType . The compiler doesn't allow that

```rust
impl<'a, T: MyTrait<'a>> TheirTrait for T {
    type RelatedType = &'a [Element];
...
}
```

The compiler tells me

```
 the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait,
 self type, or predicates
```

Reading up it seems like, what i want to do is not possible, because there should be either
• `TheirTrait<'a>`, which isn't possible, cause I don't own `TheirTrait`
• `MyTrait<'a>` should be a struct

As i further read up on the problem I didn't know what to do with this sentence from the compiler

```
Any unconstrained lifetime parameter of an `impl` is not supported
 if the lifetime parameter is used by an associated type.
```

On the one hand it doesn't concern me, cause my lifetime parameter should be constrained by my `MyTrait<'a>`, on the other hand it does, cause the compiler thinks, that is no real constraint and the associated types use `'a`.

Comment: A blanket implementation will fail anyway, regardless of the lifetime -- you cannot implement `IntoIterator` for all `T` because this will conflict with every other implementation of `IntoIterator`.

Comment: I will switch `IntoIterator` to some other `TheirTrait`. I was rather interested in the machinery of that scenario.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's `IntoIterator` or some other foreign trait, you just can't do a blanket implementation for a foreign trait: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=fe0fdbd4bf1d53f200ef964ebd9b464b).

Comment: What a pity. Thanks.